# Lua dependencies to be added in Installshield

Tags: lua, installshield

I am using lua5.1 ; I added 5.1.dll into my installation; but its not working properly. Any other dependencies which needs to be added in my installation for lua to work?

Comment: Tell us more about your problem. Any specific error message?

Comment: Rolland, My problem is I am using lua 5.1 in my c++ com dll application in Windows environment. In Instalshield project of my application, I have added lua5.1.dll;for lua dependency I have added C Runtime also. In my development machine I had installed lua. So if I install my application its working fine. If I install my application in a fresh PC without having lua installed. My com dll is not registering because lua dll is expecting few dependecies. I digged into some level and got to know lua is dependent on VS 2005 service pack1.how to add VS2005 service pack in my installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need whatever C runtime the Lua DLL was compiled with.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic answer: To find all DLL dependencies of a given DLL or EXE, use [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (it should be bundled with your MSVS).